# Copy event handler from one Canvas to another wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove, mouseenter, eventhandler

I have a `Canvas`. Later in my code I'm creating a new `Canvas` which will be on top of the first `Canvas` and should have some of the first `Canvas`'s properties.

I was able to set every thing I wanted. All that's left are to register the new `Canvas`'s `MouseEnter` and `MouseMove` events to the same event handler which the original `Canvas` is registered to.

Is that a way of doing that? I googled it but didn't find what I was looking for.

**Example:**

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     ////// some code
}

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;

Canvas c2 = new Canvas();
///// I want to do something like this:
c2.MouseEnter = c.MouseEnter;
```

Comment: The easiest and cleanest solution would be to move event handlers of first canvas into public methods which you then can call from second canvas events.

Comment: are you getting any error while using like this?

Comment: Haven't tried that, and I prefer not to, because the Canvases are located in different dll projects.

Comment: It sounds to me that you should probably change your design a little. Why are you interchanging the canvases and why is it important to handle the event on the hidden canvas?

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for [Event Bubbling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events)

```
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas();
canvas1.Width = 200;
canvas1.Height = 200;
canvas1.Background = Brushes.Black;
canvas1.MouseDown += canvas1_MouseEnter;

Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas();
canvas2.Width = 100;
canvas2.Height = 100;
canvas2.Background = Brushes.Red;            
canvas1.Children.Add(canvas2); //canvas1 events will get fired for canvas2 also
```